# MVC - Returning a model from controller for Edit Profile

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to MVC and not finding an example on the proper way of returning a typed model to the view. I need to create a view to allow an authenticated user to edit some of their profile.

As a test I created a controller action that returns an ApplicationUser model and view page that displays the profile in form fields. This works, but it contains all of the user profile and that's not what I want. To test I wrote the following:

```
Public ActionResult EditProfile()
{
    ApplicationUser user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());

    return View(user)
}
```

Of course, this does work and I realize I can display whatever I like in the view, though I'm not sure if it's a best practice to be returning all of the user's profile to the view when I only need to allow editing a few of their settings.

So I created a new ViewModel with only the fields needed and a new view based on that model. It works, but I still don't feel I'm doing it properly. In the controller action I did this:

```
public ActionResult EditProfile()
{
    ApplicationUser user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
    EditProfileViewModel model = new EditProfileViewModel();

    model.Email = user.Email;
    model.Company = user.Company;
    model.Name = user.Name;
    model.PhoneNumber = user.PhoneNumber;
    model.CountryCode = user.CountryCode;
    model.StateProvince = user.StateProvince;
    model.Language = user.Language;
    model.StateProvinceCode = user.StateProvinceCode;

    return View(model);
}
```

This just seems unnecessary and horrible to maintain. I'm sorry for asking such a basic question. I have honestly searched the 'net for examples and I know they are out there, but I'm not finding what I feel applies to my question.

Btw, the controller is decorated with [Authorize] and so I assume this action/view is only be accessed by an authenticated user.

I will understand better if someone could show me an example of the proper way of populating a model and passing it to the controller. Seems this should be able to be done in just a couple of lines of code.

Comment: Drop a constructor in your viewmodel that receives the domain model. Easier o maintain. new EditProfileViewModel(user);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first of all there is nothing to worried about as everything is handled on server side. if you wish to create custom model its seems overload as you have to now do 2 more transaction

1. Copy data from original model to customized model.
2. In `[HttpPost]` action you have to get original model data and overwrite newly updated field from customized model.

Better if you use original model, just take necessary fields in view and in `[HttpPost]` action you need to fetch original record and replace fields get from the view.

Comment: You are saying that my first approach is acceptable (returning user to the view) and that the only thing I need to worry about is displaying the necessary fields to the user? I definitely like that and that would be much easier to maintain. I just didn't think that was the correct approach. Learning curve... :S

Comment: Yes, but if you do that client side, by using ajax in that case you need to use custom model. but here is fine

Comment: Oh this greatly simplifies things AND my understanding. No wonder I wasn't finding examples of how to accomplish my second approach. Thank you Rashmin.

Comment: I do see one issue for this particular view. When a user edits their profile they have to confirm their password. The ConfirmPassword field is not contained in the original model. Somehow I need to pass the NewPassword and ConfirmPassword back to the [HttpPost] action so they can be compared before changing Password. These two fields aren't in the user model of course. How might I handle this type of situation where the view posts required information that's not in the model?

Comment: @rwkiii You can take Html.TextBox for confirm password. do not bind with TextboxFor. give some name attribute and place validation client side, while posting the form you can get the value in form["confirmpassword"]. compare both, if true save the detail otherwise show appropriate message to the user.

Comment: I'm smiling. I think you have just taught me a lot. This is very helpful. I think I understand what you are telling me. Thank you again.